# How to evaluate a string variable as factor in the emmeans() command in R?

Tags: r, eval, emmeans

I would like to assign a variable with a custom factor from an ANOVA model to the emmeans() statement. Here I use the oranges dataset from R to make the code reproducible. This is my model and how I would usually calculate the emmmeans of the factor store:

```
library(emmeans) 
oranges$store<-as.factor(oranges$store)
model <- lm (sales1 ~ 1 + price1 + store ,data=oranges)
means<-emmeans(model, pairwise  ~ store, adjust="tukey")
```

Now I would like to assign a variable (lsmeanfact) defining the factor for which the lsmeans are calculated.

```
lsmeanfact<-"store"
```

However, when I want to evaluate this variable in the emmeans() function it returns an error, it basically does not find the variable lsmeanfact, so it does not evaluate this variable.

```
means<-emmeans(model, pairwise  ~ eval(parse(lsmeanfact)), adjust="tukey")
Error in emmeans(model, pairwise ~ eval(parse(lsmeanfact)), adjust = "tukey") : 
  No variable named lsmeanfact in the reference grid
```

How should I change my code to be able to evaluate the variable lsmeanfact so that the lsmeans for "plantcode" are correctly calculated?

Comment: You should include an example of `data` to make the problem reproducible

Comment: thanks, I just did it :-)

Comment: Can't you just do `emmeans(model, lsmeanfact)`? The 2nd arg can be a character value. You can do the pairwise part using `pairs()` on the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `reformulate` function.

```
library(emmeans)
lsmeanfact<-"store"

means <- emmeans(model, reformulate(lsmeanfact, 'pairwise'), adjust="tukey")
```

Or construct a formula with `formula`/`as.formula`.

```
means <- emmeans(model, formula(paste('pairwise', lsmeanfact, sep = '~')), adjust="tukey")
```

Here both `reformulate(lsmeanfact, 'pairwise')` and `formula(paste('pairwise', lsmeanfact, sep = '~'))` return `pairwise ~ store`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do anything special at all. The `specs` argument to `emmeans()` can be a character value. You can get the pairwise comparisons in a separate call, which is actually a better way to go anyway.

```r
library(emmeans)

model <- lm(sales1 ~ price1 + store, data = oranges)

lsmeanfact <- "store"

( EMM <- emmeans(model, lsmeanfact) )
##  store emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  1       8.01 2.61 29     2.67     13.3
##  2       9.60 2.30 29     4.89     14.3
##  3       7.84 2.30 29     3.13     12.6
##  4      10.44 2.35 29     5.63     15.2
##  5      10.19 2.28 29     5.53     14.9
##  6      15.22 2.28 29    10.56     19.9
## 
## Confidence level used: 0.95

pairs(EMM)
##  contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
##  1 - 2      -1.595 3.60 29 -0.443  0.9976 
##  1 - 3       0.165 3.60 29  0.046  1.0000 
##  1 - 4      -2.428 3.72 29 -0.653  0.9856 
##  1 - 5      -2.185 3.50 29 -0.625  0.9882 
##  1 - 6      -7.209 3.45 29 -2.089  0.3206 
##  2 - 3       1.761 3.22 29  0.546  0.9936 
##  2 - 4      -0.833 3.23 29 -0.258  0.9998 
##  2 - 5      -0.590 3.23 29 -0.182  1.0000 
##  2 - 6      -5.614 3.24 29 -1.730  0.5239 
##  3 - 4      -2.593 3.23 29 -0.802  0.9648 
##  3 - 5      -2.350 3.23 29 -0.727  0.9769 
##  3 - 6      -7.375 3.24 29 -2.273  0.2373 
##  4 - 5       0.243 3.26 29  0.075  1.0000 
##  4 - 6      -4.781 3.28 29 -1.457  0.6930 
##  5 - 6      -5.024 3.23 29 -1.558  0.6314 
## 
## P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 6 estimates
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Moreover, in any case what is needed in `specs` are the *name(s)* of the factors involved, not the factors themselves. Note also that it was unnecessary to convert `store` to a factor before fitting the model